# Как запустить отредактированный файл C++ в терминале Linux Ubuntu быстрее всего (кратчайшей командой)?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, консоль, g++

Я пользуюсь Ubuntu 20.10. Предположим, что у меня есть `c++` файл `testfile.cpp` в следующем каталоге `\home\username`. Я хочу его запустить в терминале, для этого я перехожу в `\home\username`, после чего выполняю следующий код в терминале:

```
g++ -o testfile testfile.cpp
./testfile
```

После чего код успешно выполняется.После чего, я редактирую код через редактор кода, сохраняю изменения в файле `testfile.cpp`, выполняю в терминале

```
cd /home/username
./testfile
```

И терминал выдаёт мне результат старого кода. Если я проделываю опять процедуру

```
g++ -o testfile testfile.cpp
./testfile
```

Все успешно работает. Посему вопрос, есть ли более короткие способы запустить `c++` файл в терминале?Я хотел бы максимально коротко запускать отредактированный файл, не прописывая каждый раз `g++ -o testfile testfile.cpp` или `make testfile` в терминале.

Comment: Запустить C++ файл вообще нельзя, можно запустить только программу, которая будет включать в себя код единицы трансляции этого файла. Соответственно после каждого редактирования необходимо будет пересобирать программу каким-либо способом. А вообще используйте IDE. Там и пересобираться все будет автоматически, и даже есть возможность менять код прямо по ходу выполнения программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ужимаете в одну команду: `g++ -o testfile testfile.cpp && ./testfile`.

Чтобы запустить повторно, не пишете ее руками, а делаете <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Если даже один раз писать надоедает, или флагов или файлов становится слишком много, то советую настроить какую-нибудь систему сборки (Make/CMake/...) и/или в своем текстовом редакторе настроить хоткей под эту команду.

Comment: Да, тоже хорошии идеи, спасибо!

Comment: *"Ужимаете в одну команду"* - это скорее ужатие двух команд в одну строчку

Answer (score 0):

если написать makefile, то можно просто make написать и все будет работать.

Если же совсем все плохо, то можно веселее.

Открываете консоль и пишите такое

```
cr() { g++ $1 -o /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out; }
```

и теперь любой с++ файл можно компилировать и запустить вот так

```
cr ~/mycpp/data/main.cpp
```

Если скомпилировать не удалось, то запускать не будет. Результат компиляции забрасываем в /tmp, что бы не засорять текущий каталог. Да, в некоторых случаях на /tmp каталоге могут быть наложены так права, что бы нельзя было исполнять там бинарники, но это отдельная тема.

Если все работает как нужно, то открываем ~/.bashrc и аккуратно добавляем в конец (там иногда может быть много другого, так что действуем по обстоятельствам).

И на последок, почему `cr`? это от `compile & run`, такая комбинация, как минимум у меня, не занята и она очень короткая.

Я бы на самом деле эту команду чуточку расширил

```
cr() { g++ -std=c++14 -Wall $1 -o /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out; }
```

а также, -pedantic/-Wextra - что бы сразу давало побольше информации.

Comment: Идея создать скрипт очень хорошая!